# oauth2 library and Netflix API return None access token

Tags: python, rest, oauth, netflix

I have been working with the protected authentication of the netflix api and the python oauth2 library. I have no problem making signed requests, however, to allow users to sign in using their netflix accounts, I am running into a few problems when I try to get the access_token, I know there cases in which OAuth doesn't return a `verifier`, even if its supposed to, however after being redirected from the authorization page of netflix I get something like this: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorized_user?oauth_token=some_token&oauth_verifier=` with the verifier empty.

I am new to the library and quite didn't understand what to do when the `verfier` is not present. Since, I successfully redirect the user to the netflix sign in/authorization page. I assume my error comes from this step which I don't fully understand. Below is a simplified (shell) version of what I am attempting. I would appreciate a push in the right direction, I read netflix documentation and read the library documentation but couldn't figure out what to do.

```
# Get request token (temporary)
resp, content = client.request(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, "GET")

if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception("Invalid response %s." % resp['status'])

request_token = dict(parse_qsl(content))

print 'Request token'
print  '  --> oauth_token          =  %s' % request_token['oauth_token']
print  '  --> oauth_token_secret   =  %s' % request_token['oauth_token_secret']
print  '  --> login_url            =  %s' % request_token['login_url']

# Redirect to netflix for user authorization

print 'Go to the following link: '
login_url = request_token['login_url']
access_token_url = '%s&oauth_consumer_key=%s' % (login_url, CONSUMER_KEY)

accepted = 'n'
while accepted.lower() == 'n':
    accepted = raw_input('Have you authorized me? (y/n) ')

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")

token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'],
                    request_token['oauth_token_secret'])

client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(parse_qsl(content))

print "Access Token:"
print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % access_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % access_token['oauth_token_secret']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you're attempting to use python-oauth2. Unfortunately this library is widely considered abandoned-ware. I would highly recommend using a maintained library. For that I can recommend [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). I'm the maintainer of rauth, for what it's worth.

Now unfortunately Netflix is not accepting new applications to their OAuth infrastructure. However I did write up an example for you that could try if you're willing to give rauth a shot. I can't promise it won't work without some tweaks, but here it is:

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service

import re
import webbrowser

request_token_url = 'http://api-public.netflix.com/oauth/request_token'
access_token_url = 'http://api-public.netflix.com/oauth/access_token'
authorize_url = 'https://api-user.netflix.com/oauth/login'
base_url = 'http://api-public.netflix.com/'

netflix = OAuth1Service(consumer_key='123',
                        consumer_secret='456',
                        request_token_url=request_token_url,
                        authorize_url=authorize_url,
                        access_token_url=access_token_url,
                        base_url=base_url)

request_token, request_token_secret = netflix.get_request_token()

oauth_callback = 'http://example.com/oauth/authorized'

params = {'oauth_callback': oauth_callback, 'application_name': 'your_app'}
authed_url = netflix.get_authorize_url(request_token, **params)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authed_url
webbrowser.open(authed_url)

url_with_token = raw_input('Copy URL from your browser\'s address bar: ')
request_token = re.search('\?oauth_token=([^&]*)', url_with_token).group(1)

s = netflix.get_auth_session(request_token, request_token_secret)

r = s.get('users/current')
print r.content
```

A couple of things to note here: Netflix makes no mention of the verifier in their documentation. So I'm guessing that's why you see none. Secondly they are returning an "authorized" request token in place. Basically this token replaces the verifier pin in their flow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much - I have followed your recommendations and I encountered a problem, netflix requires that you submit your `oauth_consumer_key` with the authorize_url. Since this a requirement of them, while using your library I get a 400 response form the server saying `<message>oauth_consumer_key is missing</message>`. Additionally, I wanted to say your library works great and removes the complexity exposed by other libs. Let me know any suggest to overcome this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: For the authorize_url you can pass any parameters you want to the function invocation and those parameters will be added onto the query string, so maybe something like this would work: `netflix.get_authorize_url(request_token, **{'oauth_consumer_key': '123', ...})`. Hope that helps and thank you for the kind words!

Comment: Thanks again. I managed to make it work now from the shell. However, when I do it from the web framework (Flask) I keep on getting the following error: raise ` `KeyError(PROCESS_TOKEN_ERROR.format(key=bad_key, raw=r.content))`. I don't really understand keyError means?

Comment: It could mean the format Netflix provided wasn't automatically decodable by rauth (it expects a form encoded response, but some providers differ). So you can pass in an arbitrary decoder function to decode the response, e.g. `s = netflix.get_auth_session(request_token, request_token_secret, decoder=json.loads)`. In case that doesn't work, it would be helpful to see the full traceback. Feel free to open an issue on Github too.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have been completing other projects. I didn't after trying the `decoder=json.loads()` I wasn't able to make it work either. I will be creating an issue on github. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the error, it was on my end. Your lib works perfectly. Once again thank you very much.